# WPF Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I observe in my WPF application warning in VIsual Studio Output panel with following text:

> WPF Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action because the
>   specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive
>   control.Action='Stop';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   *Storyboard.HashCode='65981734'*; Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter';
>   TargetElement.HashCode='49882372';
>   TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter'

How can I 'reverse' HashCode to some xaml element? How to find where that animation is attached?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to find your StoryBoard:

```
private string GetStoryBoardNameByHashCode(int hashCode)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in Resources)
    {
        if (resource.Value is Storyboard)
        {
            if (resource.GetHashCode() == hashCode)
                return ((Storyboard) resource.Value).Name;
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Execute the method like so:

```
    string storyBoardName = GetStoryBoardNameByHashCode(65981734);
```

This should be able to get the StoryBoard-Name with the HashCode (ór if you want to get the specified StoryBoard, you can return that as well). Mind you that the ResourceDictionary is on Window-scope (local) here. So, if the StoryBoards are all located in the ResourceDictionary of the Application (App.xaml) then change 'Resources' to:

```
Application.Current.Resources
```

There may be an alternative way to get all the Resources of a WPF-application instead of just the local or Application-scope, but haven't looked into this. Hopefully, this code allows you to find your problem.

Comment: Does the Storyboard object has the same hashcode on each run?

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov Half a decade late but yes, the hashcode is the same each time.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I had run into the same problem as you.

I had found that the animation's `Begin()` method didn't get called before its `Stop()` method being called. So the Runtime throw a warning that the Stop action couldn't be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I had a trailing space in my EventName.

```
<interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged ">
```

changed to

```
<interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
```