# System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, viewbox

When I run animation in wpf using storyboard I am getting following error in output window.

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action
>   because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for
>   interactive control.; Action='Stop';
>   Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   Storyboard.HashCode='57850459';
>   Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>   TargetElement.HashCode='57850459';
>   TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'

Can anyone tell me how it will affect my program and how to remove it?

I haven't define storyboard in .xaml file. But when code behind design file(.xaml) I have created private stoaryboard in class and i am assigning it to framework element using following syntax in code.

```
this.storyboard1.Begin(this.viewbox1, true);
```

where storyboard1 is object that I have created in class and viewbox1 is element to which I want to apply this animation.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981771/wpf-animation-warning-6-unable-to-perform-action), may be help.

Comment: Thanks.. But I have already seen this but in that case HasCode for storyboard and target Element is different. Here it is same. I think it is problem with iscontrolled parameter of begin method. But I have set it to true.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this warning, but found that the 'containingElement' specified in the Begin call must also be specified in the Stop call, which should eliminate the warning.

```
this.storyboard1.Begin(this.viewbox1, true);

this.storyboard1.Stop(this.viewbox1);
```