# System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 Storyboard issue

Tags: wpf, animation

I am facing the warning issue when using the storyboard in my custom control.

Where i have used a control called `SelectorLooping` and used storyboard begin and stop.

I have called with the Container as mentioned in the below SO link.

[System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826395/system-windows-media-animation-warning-6)

But which is not helpful in my case.

```
if (animate)
{
    this.panelAnimation.Duration = duration;
    this.panelAnimation.EasingFunction = ease;
    this.panelAnimation.From = from;
    this.panelAnimation.To = to;
    this.panningTransform.Y = to;
    this.panelStoryboard.Begin(this,true);
    this.panelStoryboard.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.Zero);
}

this.panelStoryboard.Stop(this);
```

But the warnings are not cleared with the solution.

Can any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The problem occurs due to the Storyboard.Stop() called before the Storyboard.Begin() invoked.

I have checked the condition to skip the Storyboard.Stop() calling before the Storyboard.Begin(). my problem resolved.

Thanks